# How do I insert the section name into the header?

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, fancyhdr

I'm trying to use `fancyhdr` to put the current section name into my header, but the below code just returns a blank header. I can display the current page number without a problem.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[letterspace=150]{microtype}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\chead{\rightmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\section*{sect.name}
\subsection*{sub.sect.name.a}
\section*{sub.sect.name.b}
\end{document}
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not necessary to use the packages `sectsty`, `parskip` and `fancyhdr` together with a KOMA-Script class.

This classes define the two commands `\setkomafont` and `addtokomafont` to change the font of the different elements in a document.

The class option `parskip` can be used to get a parskip instead of a parindent.

Headers and footers can be set by the package `scrlayer-scrpage` or the older `scrpage2`. Both are part of the KOMA-Script bundle.

The KOMA-Script classes have a special command for unnumbered section headings producing an entry in the page header and an entry in the table of contents: `\addsec`. Use this instead of `\section*`.

For further Information have a look at the [KOMA-Script documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf).

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[letterspace=150]{microtype}

\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}% or alternativly scrpage2  
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\chead{\headmark}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont\bfseries}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text

\begin{document}
\addsec{sect.name.1}
\subsection*{sub.sect.name.a}
\Blindtext[10]
\subsection*{sub.sect.name.b}
\addsec{sect.name.2}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for this. I'm using writelatex.com, which doesn't seem to support `scrlayer-scrpage`. If I use `scrpage2` would the rest of the code be the same?

Comment: Yes, the rest would be the same. The font element `pagehead` is then only a synonym for the font element `pageheadfoot`. You will get a warning as information that the font of the `pagefoot` is also changed. writelatex.com doesn't know `scrlayer-scrpage` because they have an older version of KOMA-Script.

Comment: Thanks again. It's working fine in TeXShop on a Mac when I use `\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}`, but not if I use `\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}`. I haven't made any other changes to the code.

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to activate the pagestyle explicitly. Now I have added the line `\pagestyle{scrheadings}`.